# Auto swallow and eject cd (from the commandline)

Tags: mount, automounting, eject, abcde

I am trying to close and eject cd from the commandline. The purpose is to rip a lot of audio cds with [abcde](https://abcde.einval.com/wiki/).

I use `eject` and `eject -t` commands to open and close the cd drive.

I mount my cdrom with this line in /etc/fstab:

```
/dev/sr0        /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0
```

The problem is that ejecting the cd means also to unmount it. After the unmount, there is no way to close it.

When I start the computer, `eject -t` works and closes the tray. But if I open it again (with `eject`) `eject -t` does not find `/dev/cdrom` because it is not mounted (the tray is open and there is no cd mounted).

Someone sees a simple solution?

P-S : Debian (unstable) system.

Comment: /dev/cdrom is not mounted if you start the computer with the tray open either, so that can't be the problem.  **Please show the exact error message from eject**.  I wonder if `eject /dev/sr0` works.

Comment: @DopeGhoti It works! the solution was so simple! Turn this into and answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Also well done for saying Debian, but please always say what version as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my past experience, `mount /dev/cdrom` will, if the tray is open, close the tray and attempt to mount a disc, if present.